# Dynamic styling based on a state

Tags: react-native, state

I am trying to add some dynamic styling in my React Native project. 
I am using a React Native Snackbar but at this moment it goes in front of my Floating Action Button. This is not by the design rules of Material design.

For that reason I need to move my FAB whenever that snackbar is active.
I am keeping this in a state but I need a styling based on that state.

At this moment I got the following code:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            snackbar: true,
        }
}
../
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginBottom: this.state.snackbar ? 50 : 0,
        backgroundColor: colors.accentColor,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 9,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 9,
    },
});
```

The error that I get is that it object is undefined. 
So I am not sure why this isn't working. 
Maybe somebody can help me out with this problem.

At this moment I got it solved in the following way:

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            snackbar: true,
        }
        Snackbar.addEventListener('show',()=>{this.setState({snackbar:true})})
        Snackbar.addEventListener('hidden',()=>{this.setState({snackbar:false})})
    }
    render() {
        return <ActionButton

                onPress={() => {this.props.nav.push(routes.takePicture)}}
                style={this.state.snackbar ? stylesFabUp : styles}
            />;
    }
}
const stylesFabUp = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginBottom: 40,
        backgroundColor: colors.accentColor,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 9,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 9,
    },
})
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        // marginBottom: this.state.snackbar ? 50 : 0,
        backgroundColor: colors.accentColor,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 9,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 9,
    },
});
```

But I don't like that solution because than I got 2 stylesheets

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to have 2 stylesheets.

Consider the following code:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      snackbar: true,
    }
    Snackbar.addEventListener('show', () => {this.setState({snackbar:true})})
    Snackbar.addEventListener('hidden', () => {this.setState({snackbar:false})})
  }

  render() {
    const fabPositionStyle = this.state.snackbar ? styles.pushUp : styles.normal

    return <ActionButton
      onPress={() => {this.props.nav.push(routes.takePicture)}}
      style={[ styles.fab, fabPositionStyle ]} 
    />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fab: {
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 9,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 9,
    backgroundColor: colors.accentColor,
  },
  pushUp: {
    marginBottom: 40,    
  },
  normal: {
    marginBottom: 0,
  },
})
```

Comment: I tried combining some styling already. But the problem is that I am using a custom component. And to have the marginBottom to take effect it should be as follows:
container:{
     marginBottom:15,
} 
Is there still away to make this work considering this limitation?

Comment: If that's the case, you can either do it with second StyleSheet as you did, or I would just write `const fabPositionStyle = this.state.snackbar ? {container: styles.pushUp} : {container: styles.normal}`. What do you think? :-)

Comment: I really like what you did :) It is much cleaner and so much nices :) But I am trying to implement it. Ben whenever I do the following ` const fabPositionStyle = this.state.snackbar ? {container:styles.pushUp} : {container:styles.normal}
        return <ActionButton

                onPress={() => {this.props.nav.push(routes.takePicture)}}
                style={[styles.container,fabPositionStyle]}
            />;` It doesnt seems to have the first styling ( And returns to it's default styling). I also get the warning that it needs an object instead of an Array.

Comment: Hmm. :-) What about this? I haven't tested it, but it could work :-).

 `render() {
   const fabPositionStyle = this.state.snackbar ? styles.pushUp : styles.normal
   const fabStyle = { container: { ...fabPositionStyle, ...styles.fab } }

   return <ActionButton
     onPress={() => {this.props.nav.push(routes.takePicture)}}
     style={fabStyle} 
   />;
 }`

Comment: Unfortunally that also didn't work :( I think I am stuck with using 2 stylesheets.