# How to use a button to change style of a TextInput

Tags: react-native

Need to make a button change the color of the font from a TextInput textbox to atleast 4 different colors.

so, i'm quite new in react-native and im having a problem to solve one of my assignments, my teacher asked us to create a button that changes the color of the font inside a Text Input text box to one of 4 different colors presets onPress , couldn't figure it out on my own and cant seem to find any tutorial with this kinda of examples, just found some tutorials that only explain how to change the color from the buttons onPress.

Comment: Hi Gustavo, welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Importantly, you should let us know what you've already tried or how you think it might work. We're not here to write code *for* you, we're here to help you write code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned this is your assignment from your teacher, I would not provide any code, but just a general guideline on how to create the code yourself so that you could try and make it yourself.

What you need to do are :

1. Create the 4 styles for the text color as const that you can refer to later.
2. You would also want to have a [state](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state) to indicate which color you want to show and change it according to the button pressed.
3. And you would need to pick the correct style from the const made from step 1 above based on the state like shown on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807555/dynamic-styling-based-on-a-state).

Hope you good luck ini finishing your assignment.

Comment: Couldn't ask for more, thank you for this guidelines it helped quite a bit, as you said an assignment its for me to solve would't want a already done code, i think i didn't phrase my questions the right way so some people thought i just wanted an easy answer, sorry about that, first time posting and english is not my main language haha. Again Thank you